# Coequalizer of an idempotent and the identity implies the idempotent splits

Tags: category-theory

I am reading "Handbook of Categorical Algebra" by Francis Borceux.  Proposition 6.5.4 is the equivalence of coequalizers, equalizers, and splittings.

Definition of splitting:

In a category $\mathcal{C}$, an idempotent $e:C\to C$
splits when there exists a retract $r,i:R\leftrightarrows C$ of $C$ such that $i\circ r=e$.

I am trying to understand the direction coequalizer implies splitting for an idempotent $e:C\to C$:

The coequalizer $\text{Coker}(e,1_C)$ exists $\implies$ $e$ splits as $e=i\circ r$ with $r,i:R\leftrightarrows C$ and $r\circ i=1_R$

In the proof, he lets $r=\text{Coker}(e,1_C)$.  Then he says "the relation $e\circ e=e=e\circ1_C$ implies the existence of a unique $i$ such that $i\circ r=e$."

I do not understand how that relation implies the existence of such an $i$.  I understand the rest of the proof, just not where $i$ comes from.

Comment: hint: what's the universal property of a coequalizer?

Comment: I think I see.  That relation shows that $e$ is another such map, so there is a unique map $R\to C$.

Comment: @S.C.  I replied to your comment, but forgot to tag you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $e\circ e=e\circ 1_C$, there is, by the universal property of the coequalizer $(R,r)$, a unique map $i:R\to C$ such that $i\circ r=e$.